# PHPDoc: Documenting a function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: php, phpdoc

What is the recommended method for documenting a class method that accepts a variable number of arguments?

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php

class Foo {
    /**
     * Calculates the sum of all the arguments.
     *
     * @param mixed [$arg1, $arg2, ...]
     *
     * @return float the calculated sum
     */
    public static function sum() {
        return array_sum(func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Note: As a general rule, I imagine this type of thing should be avoided where possible. That being said, it would be nice to still document the remaining few cases where it cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 27):

If your using a variable number of arguments and also using `PHP >= 5.6` then you are able to use variadic functions (allowing variable number of arguments) which still conforms to the PHPDoc `,...` syntax already mentioned and PHPStorm will interpret the docs properly as well. Using variadic functions eliminates needing `func_get_args()` to capture arguments into an array.

```
/**
 * @param mixed $args,... Explainatorium!
 */
function variadiculous(...$args) {
    // NOTE: $args === func_get_args()
    foreach ( $args as $arg ) {
        /* do work */
    }
}
```

PHPStorm will auto-generate the docs as `@param array $args` because technically when inside the function `variadiculous` `is_array($args)` is true. I change it to read `@param mixed $args,...` as above and when I use the hotkey to display a function signature from somewhere else in my code PHPStorm displays `variadiculous($args : ...array|mixed)` -- I recommend using this method if your using PHP >= 5.6

Answer (score 11):

In the case of the [`...` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), PHPStorm 2017.1 uses:

```
/**
 * @param Type[] ...$values One or more values.
 */
public function func(Type ...$values) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be problematic description as it implies you should pass an array as parameter which is not true.

Comment: At a glance, until you notice the `...` immediately following.

Comment: well, I didn't notice ;) a strange notation

Comment: This was fixed in 2018.1.7 (according to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29429). Now the DocBlock should match the method signature: `@param Type ...$values One or more values.`

Answer (score 10):

```
/**
 * @param mixed $numbers,... Description
 */
Public function sum ($numbers)
```

In the method, $numbers will not be used.

Comment: Details on this ",..." syntax can be found at http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html

Comment: Phpstorm does not understand this syntax and warn about argument count

Comment: @PHPst it does - at least v10 does. But you have to use 2 parameters: `($number,...$numbers);`

Answer (score 3):

Something worth noting is that with a doc block such as:

```
/**
 * @param Type[] ...$values One or more values.
 */
public function func(Type ...$values) {
    // ...
}
```

...it might seem like you could pass an array of `Type`, e.g.

```
Foo()->func([Type, Type, Type])
```

...this throws a fatal error, obviously now.

Where:

```
Foo()->func(...[Type, Type, Type])
```

...does not as you have destructured it on method call.

Anyway the point here is that I was experimenting with how PHPStorm would treat the doc block and depending on the way in which you orient your `$args` variable in your doc block, with either `...$args` or `$args,...` determines the type of hints you get back in your IDE.

I'd really like a way to suggest the values you should pass by name into the method in the exemplified image below in the case where you have an optional length of function/method parameters, with a specific order in which they should be passed.

You might think, "just set default args, `$arg1 = 'default', $arg2 = true`" which typically makes sense but in cases

Pseudo-example:

```
/**
 * @param int ...$args Hour, Minute, Second, Timezone, $arg [, ...$args]
 */
public static function createA(int ...$args) {}

/**
 * @param int $args,... Hour, Minute, Second, Timezone, $arg [, ...$args]
 */
public static function createB(int ...$args) {}

/**
 * @param int[]|int $args,... Hour, Minute, Second, Timezone, $arg [, ...$args]
 */

public static function createC(int ...$args) {}
```

[image]

...so either of:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38275992/1290575
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622600/1290575

...is the correct answer (just keeping in mind orientaton: `...$args` or `$args,...`)